# Android published app not showing

Tags: android, publishing

I published my new app on Google play store and check after 18 hours on developer console, my app shows published on production but on click of "view in play store" it shows "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First please check
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename

If app is not available in above URL. There might be wrong in manifest file as package name variation.

So if you cant able to see published app it will show as
"We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server".

send a mail to support team mail of google play they will reach you within 24 hours

[PlayStore troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9061737?hl=en&visit_id=637692689260462559-3215450131&rd=1)

[Write a mail to google playstore team here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=missing)

Comment: i mentioned android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" these lines in gradle app file, should i mentioned these lines in manifest file too?

Comment: Actually for the updates, u should mention the version code and version name in manifest file too.

Comment: It ll look something like this in manifest file
.............. <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="20500" android:versionName="2.5" package="YOURPACKAGENAME" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
............

Comment: so now should i upload with new apk file with next version mentioned in gradle file as well as manifest file.

Comment: Yes u can upload a newer version of apk. but u are supposed to contact playstore for app not published rite ?

Comment: thanks Learner, i wrote mail to Google play store team regarding this issue, and now i publishing another apk file with newer version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109869/discussion-between-indrajeet-and-learner).

Comment: Yes @Learner my app published successfully...Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that there is no certain time. However most of the times it took 3-8 hours. There is one more thing, contrary to popular belief it is not an automated process. If you do something against Google Policy they may reject your application. But sometimes they don't reject even if you do something against their policy. I know this is very confusing but it is the truth.

Answer (score 0):

May be Issue is in Configuration.

Select App in PlayStore Console

Store presence ->  pricing and distribution-> "Privately target this app to a list of organisations" .  if it is checked make it uncheck .

It will Publish your app.